# ACTION_CANCEL while touching

Tags: android, events, view, touch

I has the following class that represents a View that is touchable and draw a Slide Bar.

```
public class SlideBar extends View {
private int progress;
private int max;

private Paint background;
private Paint upground;

private RectF bar;

private boolean firstDraw;

public SlideBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    progress = 0;

    upground = new Paint();
    upground.setColor(Color.parseColor("#C2296C"));

    background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
}

private void onFirstDraw() {
    max = getWidth();
    bar = new RectF(0, 19, max, 21);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (!firstDraw) {
        onFirstDraw();
        progress = max;
        firstDraw = true;
    }

    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawRoundRect(bar, 5, 5, background);
    canvas.drawCircle(progress, 20, 9, upground);
    canvas.restore();
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    progress = value;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println(evt.getAction());
    progress = (int) evt.getX();
    invalidate();
    return false;
}
}
```

But when touching and dragging it, I receive a ACTION_DOWN, some ACTION_MOVEs then receive a ACTION_CANCEL and no further events.

Why it's happens? I don't want to cancel the event and enable it to keep dragging bar.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An `ACTION_CANCEL` happens when a parent view takes over control of one of its children views.

Take a look at the documentation around [ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method.  From the link:

1. You will receive the down event here.
2. The down event will be handled either by a child of this view group, or given to your own `onTouchEvent()` method to handle; this means you should implement `onTouchEvent()` to return true, so you will continue to see the rest of the gesture (instead of looking for a parent view to handle it). Also, by returning true from `onTouchEvent()`, you will not receive any following events in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and all touch processing must happen in `onTouchEvent()` like normal.
3. For as long as you return false from this function, each following event (up to and including the final up) will be delivered first here and then to the target's `onTouchEvent()`.
4. If you return true from here, you will not receive any following events: the target view will receive the same event but with the action `ACTION_CANCEL`, and all further events will be delivered to your `onTouchEvent()` method and no longer appear here

Comment: I realized that this only happens when adding this component into a PopupWindow, how can I intercept the events and make all of them go to it's children?

Comment: I realized that is a HorizontalScrollView that are grabbing my events.

Answer (score 62):

This will happen when parent container will intercept your touch event. Any ViewGroup that overrides [ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) can do that (ScrollView or ListView for instance).

Proper way to deal with this is to call [ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) method on your parent view once you think you need to keep the motion event.

Here's a quick example (attemptClaimDrag method is taken from android source code):

```
/**
 * Tries to claim the user's drag motion, and requests disallowing any
 * ancestors from stealing events in the drag.
 */
private void attemptClaimDrag() {
    //mParent = getParent();
    if (mParent != null) {
        mParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (iWantToKeepThisEventForMyself(event)) {
            attemptClaimDrag();
        }
        //your logic here
    } else {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when I had a ViewPager with swipeable content. The content wasn't receiving horizontal swipes because they were being intercepted by the ViewPager. I simply passed in a reference to the ViewPager into the child view, and the child now calls mParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) for all ACTION_DOWN events.

Comment: If you are using ViewPager, you should probably use ViewPager#canScroll(android.view.View, boolean, int, int, int) instead. This protected method of ViewPager is made specificly to determine whenever ViewPager should scroll content of a page or switch to a next page.

Comment: how can i requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

Comment: Wow,, I lost so much time trying to solve this problem.. Thank you guys. mParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); did the trick, and I don't event have to do mParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false); on the up event. It handle it itself.  My viewpager always was scrolling now matter what I did.

Comment: Call mParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); inside onTouchEvent. Outside [eg. on fragment level] it's not working.

Comment: Wow what a great answer! Thank you! Worked to set up onTouchListener on ViewHolder in RecycleView. Previously, SelectionTracker was interrupting the onTouchListener to be canceled and return incorrect event.y

Comment: This did not work in my case (a simple ConstraintLayout), where I needed to process all the consequent ACTION_MOVEs in the child element. I still randomly get ACTION_CANCEL after some MOVEs. I put ACTION_MOVE in the if along with DOWN and others, but no use.

Answer (score 2):

Need to disallow parent view to intercept the touch event:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            (parent as? ViewGroup?)?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            (parent as? ViewGroup?)?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        }
        else -> {
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android ACTION_CANCEL while touching**

Another alternative way it is:
You have `ViewGroup` with `View` inside.

1. The `ViewGroup`'s method `onInterceptTouchEvent()` return `false` for `ACTION_DOWN` and `true` for other cases
2. The `View` always returns `true` in `onTouch` or `onTouchEvent`
3. A user makes a guest -`ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`...

As a result you will see the next flow

1. `ACTION_DOWN` iteration:

   ```
   ViewGroup dispatchTouchEvent >start< ev = ACTION_DOWN
   ViewGroup onInterceptTouchEvent false
       View dispatchTouchEvent >start< ev = ACTION_DOWN
       View onTouch true
       View dispatchTouchEvent >finish< true
   ViewGroup dispatchTouchEvent >finish< true
   ```
2. `ACTION_MOVE` iteration:

   ```
   ViewGroup dispatchTouchEvent >start< ev = ACTION_MOVE
   ViewGroup onInterceptTouchEvent true //<- start intercepting
       View dispatchTouchEvent >start< ev = ACTION_CANCEL //<- View is notified that control was intercepted
       View onTouch true
       View dispatchTouchEvent >finish< true
   ViewGroup dispatchTouchEvent >finish< true
   ```
3. `ACTION_MOVE` iteration:

   ```
   ViewGroup dispatchTouchEvent >start< ev = ACTION_MOVE
   ViewGroup dispatchTouchEvent >finish< false
   ```

[[Android Touch event]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222691/4770877)