# MotionEvents not firing

Tags: java, android, motionevent

Im trying to draw a square on a `canvas` but only the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is run, and then the `listener` stops.

The idea is when the user touches the screen it get the x1 and y1 locations and every time the `onTouch` is fired it must draw the rect frim x1 y1 to the current location, and lastly save the last location in x2 y2 once the user lets go of the screen.

My code looks like this:

```
surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            x1=event.getX();
            y1=event.getY();
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            x2=event.getX();
            y2=event.getY();
        }
        canvas.drawRect(x1, y1, event.getX(), event.getY(), paint);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Can anyone give me an example.

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: Did you try to put a log on each event?

Comment: Yes only the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is fired and then it stops.

Comment: add implements Callback to your class like this final class Surface extends SurfaceView implements Callback

Comment: Need to check all code related to this listener, because part that you provided works fine in generic case.

Comment: What is `surfaceView` ? Is it the instance of `SurfaceView` ?

Comment: @Grishu :  Yes it is a `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Put this line inside your if condition as : `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            x1=event.getX();
            y1=event.getY();
       canvas.drawRect(x1, y1, event.getX(), event.getY(), paint);
        }`

Comment: i solved my issue a different way, i used 2 pointers to draw the square.

`public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
if(event.getPointerCount()==2)
{
holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
x1=event.getX(0);
y1=event.getY(0);
x2=event.getX(1);
y2=event.getY(1);
canvas.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
return true;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACTION_UP triggers from above code. Try the code below and you will see the log.

I think your problem may be related with the points you get. I don't know how you defined x1, y1, x2, y2 but when declared out of scope they must be final. Try this instead.

```
final SurfaceView s = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

final RectF rect = new RectF();

s.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        SurfaceHolder holder = s.getHolder();
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d("action", "down");
            rect.left = event.getX();
            rect.top = event.getY();
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            Log.d("action", "up");
            rect.right = event.getX();
            rect.bottom = event.getY();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        }

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: The x1, y1, x2, y2 are not final but i got it to work without them being final. but good answer.

Comment: I have another problem now, even when i don't lift up it still sends a ACTION_CANCEL event. Do you know why this would happen?

The log says:
ACTION_DOWN
ACTION_MOVE
ACTION_MOVE
ACTION_MOVE
ACTION_CANCEL

Comment: You just need to google it. It is explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018309/action-cancel-while-touching

Comment: Couldn't find it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            x1=event.getX();
            y1=event.getY();
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            x2=event.getX();
            y2=event.getY();

            holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

If you move your finger it calls the listener every move you do.
So this code

```
holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
```

and this code

```
canvas.drawRect(x1, y1, event.getX(), event.getY(), paint);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

Will be executed, maybe that's why it's stopping.

So I put the `drawRect` inside the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` condition, so the `drawRect` will be executed once.