# RecyclerView onClick is not working at all

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to set an `onclick` method in my `RecyclerView`. It worked on another project but not here. I searched on the web but can't figure it out. Not even the toast is popping up. Can someone, please, explain to me where I am making a mistake?

**Here's my code:**

```
private Context mContext;
private MenuImages[] mMenuImages;

public MenuAdapter(Context context, MenuImages[] menuImages){
    mContext = context;
    mMenuImages = menuImages;
}

@Override
public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, parent, false);
    MenuViewHolder viewHolder = new MenuViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindMenu(mMenuImages[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMenuImages.length;
}

public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextView;

    public MenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImageView);
        mTextView  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindMenu(MenuImages menuImage){
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(menuImage.getImageMenu());
            mTextView.setText(menuImage.getTitleImageMenu());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you missed itemView.setClickable(true);

Comment: Thank's for the quick answer, but still is not working, when i click, in my monitor i get those messages :

W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=481.59375, y[0]=620.4297, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=72911, downTime=65936, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }

Comment: Cancelling event due to no window focus :: => .setFocusable(true); :)

Comment: check your R.layout.menu_list_item ,, may be checked click able in xml for image or text or may be for parent view... if child is click able then whole cell click not work.. i guess

Comment: I think you're not close cause now i have an error, not a warning anymore that's saying

Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Comment: This means he has found the solution. Use `String.valueOf(getLayoutPosition())` to convert the integer to a String. The int is interpreted as a resource id to android, which isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're awesome. First post and really surprised by this community.
For those who may be have the same problem, it wasn't about setting focusable or clickable to true in java code but in the xml. I checked those in a child.

Comment: Just another thing, everything works great but, i still have this message in my monitor when i click for the first time on an item :

W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=481.59375, y[0]=620.4297, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=72911, downTime=65936, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 } 

Does i have to be concern by it ? And how not having this message ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, we try to be helpful :) Take a look here for your last comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823612/w-viewrootimpl-cancelling-event-due-to-no-window-focus-motionevent

Answer (score 1):

in my case I was using RecyclerView in InterceptorCardView of other class wich was preventing onClickListener of recyclerview,
when I changed it with CardView and it worked perfectly

Note: I removed clickable = "false" ,focusable = "false".

Answer (score 0):

it may be late but in your layout xml file you should add attribute clickable = "false" and also focusable = "false" to the children  view ,textview and imageview in your case