# In Android P: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent

Tags: android, android-studio, popupmenu

In `Android P`, application on start not working as expected with throwing warnings :

```
 W/ViewRootImpl: 
    Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, KeyCode = DPAD_DOWN}
```

and

```
W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, KeyCode = DPAD_DOWN} and its not allowing any action to performed.
```

Check Image for detailed warning.

*Note*: Same Application is working fine in `Android O`, but in `Android P` , sometimes the focus is missing in  `PopupMenu` items and  not getting back the focus until reboot the system. After using 
    `dispatchKeyEvent` and setting dynamically focus to the view as   `v.requestFocus();`  the application started working little better but still the warning is observed sometimes with feel like system hanged for a user. Check below code snippet for details:

```
@Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            LogUtils.d(TAG, String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
            this.getWindow().getDecorView().setFocusable(true);
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
```

My Question is, **how to set the missing focus dynamically to the** `PopupMenu` and `RecyclerView`  or how to overcome this in application running in Android P.

Please suggest, I got same type of question in stackOverflow but not a proper solution, so posting the question and waiting for all type of suggestion and answer.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a working solution to this issue? Please post here.

Comment: @user846316, still not

Answer (score 2):

In my case similar issue was caused by using onKeyDown() and KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN everywhere, including when showing a dialog on a key press.
Using onKeyUp() and KeyEvent.ACTION_UP to show dialogs and activities resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on android p when show PopupWindow

and i solved it but by `View.post()` like this:

```
getView().post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // show popup window
    }
});
```

hope can help you

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Its not helping us

Comment: I guess Wang meant to put the "requestFocus()" call in there