# How to prevent a ViewGroup from receiving ACTION_CANCEL events?

Tags: android, viewgroup, motionevent

I am at a total loss here. I have read the previous questions regarding `ACTION_CANCEL` and checked the docs. But none helps my situation.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate what I am after. I have a custom `ViewGroup` (an inner class) set as the content of an activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(GestureView(applicationContext))
    }


    private class GestureView(context: Context) : ViewGroup(context) {

        init {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        }

        override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {

        }

        override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            Log.d("GestureView", "(onInterceptTouchEvent) " +
                    MotionEvent.actionToString(ev!!.actionMasked)
            )
            return true
        }

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            Log.d("GestureView", "(onTouchEvent) " +
                    MotionEvent.actionToString(event!!.actionMasked)
            )
            return true
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I am interested in a specific motion, where one finger is kept on the screen, and the other is moving. But when I try that, I often get a series of events like these:

```
(onInterceptTouchEvent) ACTION_DOWN
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_DOWN
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_MOVE
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_MOVE
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_MOVE
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(0)
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_MOVE
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_CANCEL
(onInterceptTouchEvent) ACTION_DOWN
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_DOWN
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(0)
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_MOVE
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_MOVE
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_POINTER_UP(0)
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_MOVE
(onTouchEvent) ACTION_CANCEL
```

With `ACTION_CANCEL`, no further events are received in this motion, and I need to lift all the fingers to start over.

**Why does this cancelation happen, and how can I prevent it (continue with the gesture)?**

What I have tried and got the same results:

- Returning true or false in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.
- Using `dispatchTouchEvent()` instead of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.
- Adding `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736724/336557)) doesn't help since there is no parent view that intercepts.

Comment: I've created new project with your code and it works correctly - running on oneplus/oxygenos13

Comment: @V-master By correctly you mean you never get `ACTION_CANCEL`?

Comment: yes, I did not get cancel, only got ACTION_UP after lifting all fingers

Comment: @V-master Thanks for the feedback. I am using an old Samsung phone with Android 8.0, so it might be the phone or the older Android version.